# Spring JPA with Hibernate fiscal sequence generation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my App I'm modelling an Invoice. In my country (Italy) every invoice must have a unique sequential number without holes, that every year have to restart from 1.

I thought long and hard about the best way to implement it but I have not found a good guide about this. For now I have a `JpaRepository` where I've my custom synchronized `save()` method in which I get the last id used:

```
SELECT MAX(numero) FROM Invoice WHERE YEAR(date) = :year
```

The problem of this approach is that is not very safe because the developer should know that the save should be done only with that particular service.

Instead I'd like more an approach that is hidden to the developer.
I thought to use a `@Prepersist` method in a `@EntityListeners`. This sounds good but do get entity manager inside this class is not so simple....so maybe is not the optimal place...

Finally I thought about Hibernate Interceptor....

Please give me some hints. The problem seems a quite generic problem; so maybe there is yet a good practice to follow.

Thanks

Comment: There is another problem with using a `synchronized` method.  Synchronization works within a single JVM, not across JVMs.  So, if you scale out into a cluster, each JVM will have its own `synchronized` method but there won't be any synchronization between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem can be broken down into the following requirements:

1. **Sequentially unique**: Generate numbers in a sequence, starting from a given value (say, `1000001`) and then always incrementing by a fixed value (say, `1`).
2. **No gaps**: There must not be any gaps between the numbers.  So, if the first number generated is `1000001`, the increment is `1` and 200 numbers have been generated so far, the latest number should be `1000201`.
3. **Concurrency**: Multiple processes must be able to generate the numbers at the same time.
4. **Generation at creation**: The numbers must be generated at the time of creation of a record.
5. **No exclusive locks**: No exclusive locks should be required for generating the numbers.

Any solution can only comply with 4 out of these 5 requirements.  For example, if you want to guarantee 1-4, each process will need to take locks so that no other process can generate and use the same number that it has generated.  Therefore, imposing 1-4 as requirements will mean that 5 will have to be let gone of. Similarly, if you want to guarantee 1, 2, 4 and 5, you need to make sure that only one process (thread) generates a number at a time because uniqueness cannot be guaranteed in a concurrent environment without locking.  Continue this logic and you will see why it is impossible to guarantee all of these requirements at the same time.

Now, the solution depends on which one out of 1-5 you are willing to sacrifice.  If you are willing to sacrifice #4 but not #5, you can run a batch process during idle hours to generate the numbers.  However, if you put this list in front of a business user (or a finance guy), they will ask you to comply with 1-4 as #5 is a purely technical issue (to them) and therefore they would not want to be bothered with it.  If that is the case, a possible strategy is:

- Perform all possible computation required to generate an invoice upfront, keeping the invoice number generation step as the very last step.  This will ensure that any exceptions that can occur, happen before the number is generated and also to make sure that a lock is taken for a very short amount of time, thereby not affecting the concurrency or performance of the application too much.
- Keep a separate table (for example, `DOCUMENT_SEQUENCE`) to keep a track of the last generated number.
- Just before saving an invoice, take an exclusive row-level lock on the sequence table (say, isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`), find the required sequence value to use and save the invoice immediately.  This should not take too much time because reading a row, incrementing its value and saving a record should be a short enough operation.  If possible, make this short transaction a nested transaction to the main one.
- Keep a decent-enough database timeout so that concurrent threads waiting for a `SERIALIZABLE` lock do not time out too fast.
- Keep this whole operation in a retry loop, retrying at least 10 times before giving up completely.  This will ensure that if the lock queue builds up too fast, the operations are still tried a few times before giving up totally.  Many commercial packages have retry count as high as 40, 60 or 100.

In addition to this, if possible and allowed by your database design guidelines, put a unique constraint on the invoice number column so that duplicate values are not stored at any cost.

Spring gives you all the tools to implement this.

- **Transactions**: Through the [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) annotation.
- **Serialization**: Through the `isolation` attribute of the `@Transactional` annotation.
- **Database access**: Through [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html), [Spring ORM](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) and [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).
- **Retries**: Through [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

I have a [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-transaction) that demonstrates using all these pieces together.

Comment: Thanks for your very clean explanation. You undestood very well requirements, and yes I want guarantee 1-4. I took a look at your code but I don't see the exclusive lock on the sequence table... In the end my question is if is a good idea generate the number in a @PrePersist method in a listener so I'm sure that whatever service or repository you call, at the end the number is always generated automatically. Thanks!

Comment: My sample avoids exclusive locks but uses a unique constraint on the invoice number instead.  The constraint can be removed and the transaction isolation can be changed to `SERIALIZABLE`, although that results in far more exceptions (transaction timeout) with any more than 10 concurrent users.  You could use the `@PrePersist` route.

Comment: So is not a bad idea use @PrePersist also if there EntityManager is not injectable?

Comment: You may be better off using an `EntityListener` instead of the `PrePersist` callback.  An entity can have many `EntityListener`s but only one `PrePersist` callback and many frameworks add a `PrePersist` callback for tracking entity state.  You may run into unexpected issues if you mix other libraries later.  Personally, I would keep the number generation code in a service and enforce invoice generation through architecture but it isn't blatantly wrong to do these kind of things in the entity layer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm following your example but unfortunally I've a org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in mypackage.Invoice when the @Retryable works. I marked this question as answered and I will open another one for this strange error. Thanks again